# Infinity loading of centrain Google Apps on Italian SIM

Tags: internet, sim-card, roaming

I have OnePlus 5 (Android 8) phone and I have 1 SIM slot with my home SIM and 2 SIM slot with Italian Prepaid card with internet data.

I am getting infinity loops when I am using centrain Google apps. For example I cannot login into YouTube, Search on Google Play, or download emails. I am always getting infinity loading. When I am on Wifi its ok and working.
Only on first or second card I am getting this problem.

What is going on? Is google blocking access to some accounting servers from different locations? I am originally from Czech Republic and now I am on vaccation in Italy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by clearing cache and data of all Google apps...
Seems apps where setuped for different country.
I am now back from Italy and SIM data alsos topped working so I did clear again and it works now.